# Oceans just out of reach

Tags: riddle

> Oceans just out of reach
>
> Minds best to be
>
> I leap from my rest
>
> Bringing sweet symphony

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the answer might be

> Sound

Oceans just out of reach

> Sounding is the act of ascertaining the depth of a body of water either using a line or pole or sound echoes. 
>  Also, as suggested by OnlyF in the comments, sound travels in waves much like the oceans.
>  Alternatively, one definition of a sound is a narrow stretch of water forming an inlet or connecting two wider areas of water such as two seas.

Minds best to be

> Top be of sound mind is to have full, unimpaired thought, memory, and cognitive understanding.

I leap from from my rest

> Vibrations travel through the air once sound is emitted. 
>  Someone resting deeply could be described as sound asleep.

Bringing sweet symphony

> The music produced in a symphony could be described as a sweet sound.

Comment: The first clue might have to do with rot13(fbhaq jnirf) as well?

Comment: That's a really good suggestion. I'll add that in.

Comment: Hexomino is correct!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

> Sound.

The explanation:

> Oceans waves are out of reach of a sound as in the body of water separated by land (similar to a bay).  To be of sound mind is best.  Musical notes leap/begin following a rest in a musical score (no sound) travel through the air and hopefully bring a sweet sound to the listener.

Thank you for trying my riddle!